# Can Apache Camel connect to an ActivationSpec in WebSphere?

Tags: spring, websphere, jndi, ibm-mq, apache-camel

In the past, I've been able to successfully connect Camel to a Message Queue exposed as a JNDI resource in WebSphere [1]. This works with a Connection Factory. Great.

Now today, I have a situation where sys admins have only provided an Activation Specification. No Connection Factory. Here's what we've got:

> - SIBus name: ________
> - Provider endpoint: ________
> - Topic space: Default.Topic.Space
> - Messaging Engine Name: ________
> - Topic name: ________

From what I've read, Activation Specification is intended for MDBs (Message Driven Beans). But Spring has some APIs for ActivationSpec -- [DefaultJmsActivationSpecFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jms/listener/endpoint/DefaultJmsActivationSpecFactory.html), for example -- so I'm optimistic I can configure Camel / Spring to work with an Activation Specification. I'm not sure that it matters, but this is an SIBus with a foreign bus.

My question is:

**Has anyone had any luck configuring Camel to communicate with an Activation Specification?**

See also:

- [What's the difference between ActivationSpec and ConnectionFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390286/whats-the-difference-between-activationspec-and-connectionfactory)
- [Spring JMS and WebSphere](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/09/spring-jms-and-websphere/)
- [Spring Support for JCA Message Endpoints](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jms.html#jms-jca-message-endpoint-manager)

[1] For reference, here's our hard-won Camel config that connects Camel to a Message Queue via a JNDI resource (Connection Factory). Since we had to piece this config together with almost no documentation, I'm hoping a similar config can be done for Activation Spec.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myTargetConnectionFactory" jndi-name="${mq.jndi-name}"/>
<bean id="jmsDestResolver" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver"/>

<bean id="myConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="myTargetConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="username" value="${mq.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="myConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestResolver" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="10" />
    <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_NONE" />
</bean>
```

Comment: here is some info in regards to AMQ config...have you seen it? http://activemq.apache.org/activation-spec-properties.html