# Spring STS 3.7 Maven not downloading ibm jars

Tags: spring-tool-suite

**Issue:** Can't add com.ibm.mq dependencies in Spring STS 3.7.

**Description:** Trying to get the following example below working in Spring STS 3.7 . Having issue trying to add the dependencies for mq jars. I can't seem to download the com.ibm.mq jars in Spring STS.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523572/spring-jms-and-websphere-mq](http://Spring%20Integration%20-%20Websphere%20MQ%20Example)

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. In Spring STS 3.7 - Under preferences -> Maven : Checked "Download repository index updates on startup" .
2. Right clicked on project - > Maven - > Add dependency
3. Did a search for com.ibm*
4. com.ibm jars came up as expected and attempted to add com.ibm.mq.

Dependency does not download.

Group Id: com.ibm

Artifact Id: com.ibm.mq

Version: 5.3.07

UPDATE 1
STS Maven Settings:
- Under Preferences -- > Maven -- > User Settings

User Settings: C:\Users\haju.m2\settings.xml
- However that file does not exist. I do have a local .m2 directory and it has the com.ibm.mq jar in it.

`<repository>
     <id>repo.spring.io.milestone</id>
     <name>Spring Framework Maven Milestone Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
    </repository>`

**Update 2 - Solution** 
- Artifact listing exists in the maven repo , however it gives a 404 when actually trying to download it. Doesn't exist in the repo. It's just listed there. Not a STS issue.

Suggestions?

Comment: What Maven repository are you using? The MQ JARs are not in the central Maven repository, and IBM does not provide a repository with these JARs (as far as I know). You will need to get the JARs from an MQ install and put them into your local repository or the repository of your organization.

Comment: I put notes above regarding STS settings ( default ) and pom file repo listed. I would think that if I couldn't find the MQ client jar it wouldn't show up in the index.  I also find the mq client jar listed above in the maven m2 repo online.

Comment: I see the issue now. The artifact is in he maven repo. However when I click on the jar to download it, it gives a 404. Artifact listing is there but doesn't exists.