# how to make Camel JMS Support for Activation Specification for Websphere

Tags: apache-camel, ibm-mq, websphere-8, spring-jms

We are trying to connect to MQ resource via activation specification. Referring some of old blog which points the camel JMS uses Spring JMS. Camel JMS have placeholder for **messageListenerContainerFactoryRef** which uses MessageListenerContainerFactory i.e., **org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer**.

We are able to make spring jms to use activation spec to connect to Websphere MQ using **org.springframework.jms.listener.endpoint.JmsMessageEndpointManager**. Refer [Spring JMS and Websphere MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523572/spring-jms-and-websphere-mq).

Now I am unable to figure out the way to bridge **JmsMessageEndpointManager** with **AbstractMessageListenerContainer** implementation. Any direction regarding the same would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think that a Spring destination resolver can help you here?

destinationResolver

null

A pluggable org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DestinationResolver that allows you to use your own resolver (for example, to lookup the real destination in a JNDI registry).

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following your answer here.

Comment: Still integrating Destination resolver with JMSEndpointmanager is challenge. It uses listener class and hands over the object to listener. Using destination helper may not help.